# How to add items to a document library when uploading a file using Rest in SP 2013?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, file-upload, rest

I am trying to add file to document library by using REST IN SP 2013 APP MODEL.

This is my code I can upload file to document library but I can't add items value to that document library in fields please look this code help me find the issue. I'm getting the error at `getItem(file){}`

```
function uploadDocument() {



            var params = document.URL.split("?")[1].split("&");
            for (var i = 0; i < params.length; i = i + 1) {
                var param = params[i].split("=");
                switch (param[0]) {
                    case "SPAppWebUrl":
                        appWebUrl = decodeURIComponent(param[1]);
                        appweburl = decodeURIComponent(param[1]);
                        //alert(appWebUrl);
                        break;
                    case "SPHostUrl":
                        targetSiteUrl = decodeURIComponent(param[1]);
                        hostUrl = decodeURIComponent(param[1]);

                        //alert(targetSiteUrl);
                        break;
                }
            }





            if (!window.FileReader) {
                alert("This browser does not support the HTML5 File APIs");
                return;
            }

            var element = document.getElementById("uploadInput");
            var file = element.files[0];
            var parts = element.value.split("\\");
            var fileName = parts[parts.length - 1];

            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function (e) {
                addItem(e.target.result, fileName);
            }
            reader.onerror = function (e) {
                alert(e.target.error);
            }
            reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);

            function addItem(buffer, fileName) {
                alert('asdsasadsa');
                var call = uploadDocument(buffer, fileName);
                call.done(function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                    alert('call.done');
                    alert(data.d);
                    var call2 = getItem(data.d);
                    call2.done(function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                        var item = data.d;
                        alert(item);
                        var call3 = updateItemFields(item);
                        call3.done(function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                            var div = jQuery("#message");
                            div.text("Item added");
                        });
                        call3.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                            failHandler(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown);
                        });
                    });
                    call2.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        failHandler(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown);
                    });
                });
                call.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    failHandler(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown);
                });
            }

            function uploadDocument(buffer, fileName) {
                alert('hi this is uploaddoc');
                alert(appWebUrl);
                var libraryName = 'Documents';

                var url = appWebUrl + "/_api/SP.AppContextSite(@TargetSite)/web/lists/getByTitle(@TargetLibrary)/RootFolder/Files/add(url=@TargetFileName,overwrite='true')?"+
                "@TargetSite='" + targetSiteUrl + "'" +
            "&@TargetLibrary='" + libraryName + "'" +
            "&@TargetFileName='" + fileName + "'";
                var call = jQuery.ajax({
                    url: url,
                    type: "POST",
                    data: buffer,
                    processData: false,
                    headers: {
                        Accept: "application/json;odata=verbose",
                        "X-RequestDigest": jQuery("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
                        "Content-Length": buffer.byteLength
                    }
                });

                return call;
            }

            function getItem(file) {
                alert(file);
                alert('getItem(file)');
                var call = jQuery.ajax({
                    url: file.ListItemAllFields.__deferred.uri,
                    type: "GET",
                    dataType: "json",
                    headers: {
                        Accept: "application/json;odata=verbose"
                    }
                });

                return call;
            }

            function updateItemFields(item) {
                alert('updateItemFields');
                alert(item.Id);
                var now = new Date();
                var call = jQuery.ajax({
                    url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl +
                        "/_api/Web/Lists/getByTitle('Documents')/Items(" +
                        item.Id + ")",
                    type: "POST",
                    data: JSON.stringify({
                        "__metadata": { type: "SP.Data.DocumentsItem" },
                        Title: now.getFullYear()
                    }),
                    headers: {
                        Accept: "application/json;odata=verbose",
                        "Content-Type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                        "X-RequestDigest": jQuery("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
                        "IF-MATCH": item.__metadata.etag,
                        "X-Http-Method": "MERGE"
                    }
                });

                return call;
            }

            function failHandler(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                var response = JSON.parse(jqXHR.responseText);
                var message = response ? response.error.message.value : textStatus;
                alert("Call failed. Error: " + message);
            }
        }
```

Comment: so does this getItem method work ? Do you get the exact Item?

Answer (score 1):

I have test your code and I came to a conclusion:

As you are developing your app, you need to declare instance of the site context, each time you make an ajax request, try to use the cross-domain, because you are trying to access or post data out of the APP, if you do not will always get those errors.

Developed a trivial solution, follows the code below:

```
'use strict';

var appWebUrl, appweburl, targetSiteUrl, hostUrl;

function uploadDocument() {

var params = document.URL.split("?")[1].split("&");
for (var i = 0; i < params.length; i = i + 1) {
    var param = params[i].split("=");
    switch (param[0]) {
    case "SPAppWebUrl":
        appWebUrl = decodeURIComponent(param[1]);
        appweburl = decodeURIComponent(param[1]);
        //alert(appWebUrl);
        break;
    case "SPHostUrl":
        targetSiteUrl = decodeURIComponent(param[1]);
        hostUrl = decodeURIComponent(param[1]);

        //alert(targetSiteUrl);
        break;
    }
}

if (!window.FileReader) {
    alert("This browser does not support the HTML5 File APIs");
    return;
}

var element = document.getElementById("uploadInput");
var file = element.files[0];
var parts = element.value.split("\\");
var fileName = parts[parts.length - 1];

var reader = new FileReader();
reader.onload = function(e) {
    addItem(e.target.result, fileName);
}
reader.onerror = function(e) {
    alert(e.target.error);
}
reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);

function addItem(buffer, fileName) {
    alert('asdsasadsa');
    var call = uploadDocument(buffer, fileName);
    call.done(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        alert('call.done');
        alert(data.d);
        var call2 = getItem(data.d);
        call2.done(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            var item = data.d;
            updateItemFields(item);
        });
        call2.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            failHandler(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown);
        });
    });
    call.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        failHandler(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown);
    });
}

function uploadDocument(buffer, fileName) {

    var libraryName = 'Documents';

    var url = appWebUrl + "/_api/SP.AppContextSite(@TargetSite)/web/lists/getByTitle(@TargetLibrary)/RootFolder/Files/add(url=@TargetFileName,overwrite='true')?" + "@TargetSite='" + targetSiteUrl + "'" + "&@TargetLibrary='" + libraryName + "'" + "&@TargetFileName='" + fileName + "'";
    var call = jQuery.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: "POST",
        data: buffer,
        processData: false,
        headers: {
            Accept: "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "X-RequestDigest": jQuery("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
            "Content-Length": buffer.byteLength
        }
    });

    return call;
}

function getItem(file) {
    var callURL = convertURLCrossDomain(file.ListItemAllFields.__deferred.uri);
    var call = jQuery.ajax({
        url: callURL,
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        headers: {
            Accept: "application/json;odata=verbose"
        }
    });

    return call;
}

function updateItemFields(item) {                       
    var callitemType = getItemTypeForListName('Documents');
    callitemType.done(function(itemType) {
        var callURL = convertURLCrossDomain(_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/Web/Lists/getByTitle('Documents')/Items(" + item.Id + ")");
        var nowString = new Date().getFullYear().toString();
        var itemJSON = {
            "__metadata": {
                "type": itemType.d.ListItemEntityTypeFullName
            },
            "Title": nowString
        };
        var call = jQuery.ajax({
            url: callURL,
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
            data: JSON.stringify(itemJSON),
            headers: {
                "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
                "X-HTTP-Method": "MERGE",
                "If-Match": item.__metadata.etag
            }
        });
        call.done(function() {
            var div = jQuery("#message");
            div.append("Item added sucess!");
        });
        call.fail(function() {
            var div = jQuery("#message");
            div.append("Item added failed");
        });
    });
    callitemType.fail(function(result) {
        failHandler(result, "", "");
    });
}


function failHandler(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    var response = JSON.parse(jqXHR.responseText);
    var message = response ? response.error.message.value : textStatus;
    alert("Call failed. Error: " + message);
}

/*
    Function convertURLCrossDomain created by b1c10 all right reserved
*/
function convertURLCrossDomain(url) {
    var urlsplitted = url.split('/');
    var newURL = "";
    var startwrite = false;
    for (var i = 0; i < urlsplitted.length; i++) {
        if (urlsplitted[i].toLowerCase() == "_api") {
            newURL += appWebUrl + "/_api/";
            startwrite = true
        } else if (urlsplitted[i].toLowerCase() == "web") newURL += "SP.AppContextSite(@TargetSite)/web/"
        else if ((i + 1) == urlsplitted.length) {
            if (urlsplitted[i].indexOf("?") > -1) {
                newURL += urlsplitted[i] + "&@TargetSite='" + targetSiteUrl + "'";
            } else {
                newURL += urlsplitted[i] + "?@TargetSite='" + targetSiteUrl + "'";
            }
        } else if (startwrite) newURL += urlsplitted[i] + "/";
    }
    return newURL;
}

function getItemTypeForListName(name) {
    var call = $.ajax({
        url: convertURLCrossDomain("_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + name + "')?$select=ListItemEntityTypeFullName"),
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        headers: {
            Accept: "application/json;odata=verbose"
        },
    });
    return call;
    //this return "SP.Data.listnameItems" but not is the correct then i have created method to prevent error in update item;
}
```

}

And other, with that your code had problems updating the list item. and had to restructure, tested for me and work fine :)

Regarding your code added two methods:
convertURLCrossDomain (Url);
getItemTypeForListName (ListName);

Hope this help.

Thanks.